# A question about using a 12-bit ADC value in embedded C

Tags: stm32, adc, c

I'm using the following STM32's HAL function to read a 12-bit ADC value (0 to 4095) from a channel:

```
__weak uint32_t HAL_ADC_GetValue(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
  {
  /* Note: This function is defined into this file for library reference. */
  /* Function content is located into file stm32f3xx_hal_adc_ex.c   */
      
  /* Return ADC converted value */ 
  return hadc->Instance->DR;    
}
```

As you see, the function above returns a 32-bit unsigned integer.

At the start of my code I declare the grabbed ADC value as `volatile uint16_t adc_val`.

At some point I call the HAL functions and assign it to the `adc_val` as follows:

```
HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);
if (HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 5) == HAL_OK) {
  adc_val = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
}
HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
```

Now `HAL_ADC_GetValue` returns 32-bit unsigned but `adc_val` is declared as 16-bit unsigned.

My question is, do we need casting here? And what happens if we keep it like in my code without casting? (The reason I want to use 16-bit unsigned is to make the code faster since 16-bit unsigned is sufficient for a 12-bit ADC)

Comment: Casting will just keep the compiler from maybe issuing a warning.  The compiler will just truncate the top 16 bits. Why do you think 16 bit operations will be faster on a 32bit machine? It’s more likely to be slower as extra code gets added to manage 16 bits. It would be slower on an 8 or 16 bit machine. If in doubt do some benchmarking.

Comment: I don't know a thing about the STM32 architecture. If this were a DEC Alpha I'd say you are pretty much stuck with masking and shifting things around and the associated price you'd pay. They absolutely ***refused*** to include any lane-shifting code in that architecture. But in contrast most other architectures do include some means of lane-shifting and masking as part of their internal structures. To write C code that uses an architecture well requires a study of that architecture and an understanding of the specific C compiler you are stuck using on it. All of that matters a lot.

Comment: @jonk, the architecture is Arm Cortex M. Assuming it is reading/writing to native 32bit ram, doing 32 bit ops is going to be the fastest.

Comment: @Kartman I still don't know specifics regarding it's abilities internally nor do I know anything about the C compiler in use and how well it is targeted to the architecture. So I can't say much one way or another. I probably should have kibbitzed.

Comment: @jonk, i didn’t think kibbitzing was kosher except on the Sabbath…..  what the hell is ‘kibbitzing’?

Comment: @Kartman It just means I was just talking out loud and commenting on the proceedings around me without contributing anything worth much. As I said, I should have just stayed out of it.

Comment: @jonk, i wasn’t having a go at you, just filling in the blanks as it were.

Comment: @jonk ... Alpha had `SLL`, `SRL`, `SLA`, `SRA`, also `SEXTW` etc and the wackier `S4ADDL` etc.  No shifting?

Comment: @jonathanjo Zero built-in lane shifting. I'm talking about inside the proc. Not outside assembly instructions, which I don't care about. If you see the architecture itself you can see that it is 64-bit lanes and NO lane-shifting to be seen. Of course, people want lane-shifting and there are means by which to get it. But not intrinsically within the Alpha hardware design. I was there. It was probably the most RISC processor I've ever seen. They went crazy hog-wild RISC on this one. If you care, just dig into the pipeline and exception event handling. That will fry your brain.

Comment: @jonk I'd really love to hear more about that https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139663/alpha-channel

Comment: @jonathanjo It was in the early 1990's -- can't recall exactly but I think I got into it around 1993 or so? Anyway, no time for chatting. It's literally bedtime for me and I should have already gone to bed and started playing Return to Monkey Island or something to go to sleep! There's plenty in the docs on the exception issues -- it's what literally caused me to stop any ideas of working with the Alpha! Restarting from that mess drove me bat-crazy! I'm sure the documentation authors also went crazy writing it! They froze the entire pipeline and sometimes allowed a restart from it!!!

Comment: @jonathanjo - I think jonk is just trying to explain the fact that early Alpha had no unaligned loads, and not byte or halfword loads, only aligned 32 and 64-bit loads.  That let them avoid some muxing/decoding in the load/store hardware, and make the ECC granules for their L1d cache be 32-bit instead of 8-bit for much lower overhead, without ever needing an internal RMW cycle to update the containing word's ECC data.  (So pipelining is easier). It's the one modern CPU where [Can modern x86 hardware not store a single byte to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46721075) is actually true.

Comment: I wouldn't have called that "lane shifting", that's a weird way to describe it.  No idea where @jonk got that terminology from.  "Lane shifting" sounds to me like how you'd describe a SIMD shuffle, like ARM `vtbl` or `vzip`.  Anyway, later Alpha did add byte load/store.  I forget if that was guaranteed to be fast, or if it was allowed to be  implemented by trapping to a helper function like unaligned loads on RISC-V.  But compatible code couldn't use it, at least not with software CPU detection and dispatching, so the existence of Alphas without byte accesses was a problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes: What's missing in the Alpha is not "lane shifting", but rather the existence of separate write-enables for different parts of each word.  Many languages guarantee that no race conditions will arise if multiple threads write to different parts of a byte array, provided only that no two threads access the same byte, and have no way of indicating when this guarantee is or is not required for correct operation.

Comment: @supercat: Yes, for C11 (the first version to have a memory model that mentions threads) the thread-safety guarantee is essentially the same as C++11, so [C++ memory model and race conditions on char arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19903338) discusses it.  C11 on Alpha would need to use CHAR_BIT = 32, or have narrow accesses use software atomic RMWs if it was ever possible for another thread to have a reference to memory adjacent to where we're doing a narrow store.  Interesting point about the language not giving a way to hint when access to bytes near other shared bytes is happening.

Comment: @PeterCordes: IMHO, the lack of any sort of hinting in popular languages is a major contributor to the Alpha's downfall.  If a language allowed code to explicitly indicate that such accommodation was required, reliance upon such accommodation in code which doesn't specify it could be deprecated in favor of having code specify such reliance.  A system like the Alpha could then efficiently process code that was written for other systems and indicated when it relied upon precise byte semantics, and even compilers for other systems could benefit from cases where such semantics aren't required.

Comment: @PeterCordes The Alpha designers used the term lane-shifting for it, in fact. Terms change over time. But at *that* time and with *those* designers, that's the term for supplying a shift feature (special muxing) attached to the bus. It was obvious to me at the time, from usage, and I never questioned its use by them.

Comment: @PeterCordes: For example, if `p` is a `char*` that's known to be suitably aligned for 32-bit access, and doesn't require byte-level isolation, replacing a sequence like `p[0] |= 1; p[1] |= 2; p[3] |= 4;` with `*(uint32_t*)p |= 0x04000201;` would likely improve efficiency.

Comment: @jonk: Thanks, yeah I can see that terminology getting used to describe a hardware design.  But what software wants is byte (and unaligned) loads and especially stores, not "lane shifting" per-se, only happening to require that.  (And I can also see why others would misinterpret your earlier comments on "lane shifting [code]" to describe a *software* technique for accessing bytes of a word, or some other software-visible thing, so it sounded like you were claiming that Alpha only allowed "vertical" operations like bitwise AND on whole words, not shifts.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It has (had?) more than one usage. Sometimes, a lane-shift was just wires changing their power-of-2 meaning and there was no logic, at all. For example, it is a lane-shift to take a pointer and "move it two places to the left" before it reaches one of the inputs to an adder. In this case, there's no mux. But there is a lane-shift (in your head, anyway.) So it was used in two cases then that I knew of. Context told me what was meant. But DEC didn't want the propagation delays involved in adding byte-moving instruction decode features to align into register destinations.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> (The reason I want to use 16-bit unsigned is to make the code faster since 16-bit unsigned is sufficient for 12-bit ADC)

Why would 16 bits be faster than 32 bits on a 32 bit MCU? Your rationale for messing around with this to begin with doesn't make much sense. If you used 16 bits to save 2 bytes of RAM, that would have been a valid rationale.

---

> make the code faster

Declaring variables as `volatile` just for the heck of it, is an excellent way of making your program **much slower**. Stop making your program slower if you want it to be faster...

The only thing that must be `volatile` here is the actual register declaration.

In general, it isn't wise to attempt manual code optimization unless you have in-depth knowledge of C and how C code translates to machine code for the given target.

---

> My question is, do we need casting here?

No. The *only* relevant quote here is from the C standard ISO 9899:2018 6.3.1.3 regarding unsigned/signed integer conversions (normative text):

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.<sup>60)</sup>

Where further info is given by the foot note 60 (informative text):

> 60. The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression.

In theory, the above says that you'd take the `uint32_t` value, write it down with pen & paper and repeatedly subtract `UINT16_MAX + 1` from it, until you get in range with what would fit inside a `uint16_t`

Which as it happens is the same as taking the `uint32_t` value modulus the maximum for the `uint16_t`. Which as it happens is the same as simply discarding the most significant bytes.

That being said, it is good practice to never have any implicit conversions in your code. Standards like MISRA C disallow such conversions, as one example. So it isn't wrong to add a manual cast as a way of self-documenting code or adding one for MISRA compliance. But in this specific case, it doesn't change anything in practice.

Comment: Upvoted.  Your comments about `volatile` and whether 16-bit is faster/slower are excellent, and very helpful quotation and reference to the  portion of the current ISO standard.  I disagree about "The _only_ relevant quote".  The question doesn't say what C compiler is in use, what strictness flags might be in use, or which standards (if any) are applicable in that project.  GCC's position is "GCC attempts to follow one or more versions of that standard", and for example `gcc` has at least half a dozen flags for various C standards, but the default isn't your "_only_ relevant" standard.

Comment: @jonathanjo It's a bit of a misconception, there is only one C standard. As with any technical standard, ISO withdraws the previous standard when a new one is released. The old one is outdated and should no longer be used. Of course this is hard to apply in practice on programming since it takes a while for compilers and tools to be updated, and even longer to educate the conservative/stubborn part of the programmer population (a lot aren't even up to date with C99, 23 years after its release...).

Comment: @jonathanjo As for gcc & others, they seek to provide backwards compatibility for the sole purpose of maintaining old programs. Depending on which version you have, gcc only presents two standards: std=gnu17, which is "relaxed standard C with extensions" and std=c17 "relaxed standard C", which is ISO 9899:2018 but not to the letter. You can also force it to become a conforming compiler with `-std=c17 -pedantic`.

Comment: I respect the opinion that there's "only one standard", but it's somewhat of a theoretical ideal.  For example it doesn't cover maintenance well.  We don't recompile and redeploy our projects because a standards organisation has issued a new standard.  And in every serious project I've worked on, we make a conscious decision about what standards to adopt, and under what conditions those standards will change.  When we do maintenance on old projects (in my organisations) we usually do it with toolchains which we have kept operational for this purpose.

Comment: @jonathanjo Actually the relatively young engineering trade of software is still struggling heavily with proper engineering practices and standardization. More mature engineering trades like mechanical engineering are far more used at following new standards. When the new machinery directive was released in EU around 2010, everyone was just falling in line, adapting and updating. There are very few quacks developing new mechanical parts according to old, withdrawn standards, for example. Whereas a huge part of the software industry still practices quackery instead of engineering.

Comment: @jonathanjo And naturally, no matter engineering trade, nobody goes around updating old products that were released before a standard was updated, unless there's a demand for it. Legislation typically allows products already released on the market to be excluded from updates in the latest technical standard.

Comment: I certainly agree there are huge problems in the software industry!

Comment: Would a union be appropriate in terms of optimization here?

Comment: @ScottSeidman Assuming you mean `typedef union { uint16_t u16 [2]; uint32_t u32} my_adc_t;` then probably not. This union will have the same endianess as the CPU. However, ADCs do not necessarily follow CPU endianess (especially not when external) and they almost always have the option to left/right "align" (shift) data as well. Meaning that some 12 bit ADC with a 16 bit result register, making a reading of value 0x123, might present it either as `0x0123` or `0x2301` or `0x1230` or `0x3012`... or 32-bit flavours of those.

Comment: The 32 bit versions being `0x00000123` (big endian), `0x23010000` (little endian), `0x12300000` (left aligned big endian),  `0x00003012` (left aligned little endian). Given those possible combinations, now what does `my_adc_t adc = { .u32 = ADCREG; }; ... adc.u16[0]` even mean? I have no idea - since there's no way of knowing without reading up on the specific ADC.

Comment: (The correct approach would be to have the ADC driver convert the raw data from ADC into a suitable format for the CPU endianess and then take it from there. I wouldn't automatically assume that something like ST's so called "HAL" does anything like that. Sometimes their "HAL" is just a thin wrapper above register access.)

Comment: I didn't read all of the comments (WOW, this one is popular!), but I wanted to point out another potential pitfall: **Which way does this HAL library justify the ADC result?**  If it's right-justified, then a simple cast is fine, albeit unnecessary.  If it's left-justified, then you could lose everything and end up with all zeros.  (one reason to left-justify is to present the result as a fraction of the reference, using fixed-point format `0.x`, which can be a useful step in keeping a relevant set of units)

Answer (score 5):

*Updated after discussion*

Harbison and Steele (and every version of every standard I've looked at) say no cast is required, and that the implicit conversion simply throws away the high-order bits.

> If the destination type is shorter than the source type and both the original and destination types are unsigned, then the conversion can be performed simply by discarding excess high-order bits from the original value.  The bit pattern of the result respresentation will be equal to the *n* low-order bits of the original respresentation, where *n* is the number of bits in the destination type.
> -- *C: A Reference Manual* (5th ed) section 6.2.3

If you have uncertainties about what the implicit conversations are, it's well worth reading up on them, and it is *always* worth finding out *exactly* what your compiler does for the flags and options you're using.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139697/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathanjo-a-question-about-using-a-12-bit-adc-value-in).

Answer (score 2):

That is perfectly valid code. You don't need to do anything, no casting required.

Answer (score 2):

As the others above say, there is no need for casting.

HOWEVER, it is a good idea to cast it so that it is clear to later engineers exactly what is happening.

Comment: There is an alternative view (which I generally subscribe to): never use a cast if there is another way to do it, because it basically switches off a lot of checking.  In this particular case, I'd normally suggest something like `shortvar = longfunc() & 0xffff;` which not only deals with the sizes but explicitely says what we think should happen.  Indeed, we know it's 12 bits: `shortvar = longfunc() & 0xfff;`

Comment: @jonathanjo A better view to subscribe to is to never allow any implicit conversions anywhere in your code and never write any code relying on them either. Your examples here look like they come with 2 implicit conversions, can you point them out and explain them? Do you actually know the type of `0xffff` on a generic computer and why the compiler picked it? And so on. Programmers that don't know/care about implicit promotions are the kind who end up with mysterious bugs and then after a long while of debugging come up with desperate "just cast here and it works" without even knowing why.

Comment: @Lundin We appear to be agreeing that many defensive programming techniques are useful, including avoiding implicit conversions.  Which ones are considered acceptable depends on a lot of things, not least of which is the intended audience, longevity, and deployment of any particular piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

The rational about using a 16-bit wide type aside:

It's often times a good idea to use explicit type conversions (aka casts), if you are aware of a potential dangerous type conversion (i. e. potential loss of information) and want to indicate your awareness to the reader of your code and/or a static analysis tool.

So in this case, the type conversion of a 32-bit type to a 16-bit type might cause loss of information. But if you know that `HAL_ADC_GetValue()` will always return only 12 bit of information, you should use a cast. Or to be more precise: If you know that the return value of `HAL_ADC_GetValue()` will not lose information when it is assigned to a 16-bit type. It's not necessary syntactically, of course.

However, I'm not a fan of avoiding implicit type conversions altogether. Many implicit type conversions don't do any harm. Just set up a static analyzer to flag all implicit conversions and see what happens. And then look at your code after turning all implicit conversions to explicit ones. Not good. You not only bloated your code, you also turned explicit type conversions into a brain-dead activity.

> (The reason I want to use 16-bit unsigned is to make the code faster
> since 16-bit unsigned is sufficient for a 12-bit ADC)

If you care about speed, you could use the fast-types of `stdint.h`. But if you have a look in your `stdint.h`, you'll most likely find that `uint_fast16_t` is typedef'd to `unsigned int` anyway. Plus you kind of obfuscate the actual width of the data type.